# How to connect my node to mainnet network on NEAR protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

It seems that `nearup` does not have the support for mainnet. How can I connect manually?

Comment: There is a related issue https://github.com/near/docs/issues/438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this guide https://docs.near.org/docs/validator/deploy-on-mainnet. If you are not a validator, simply skip the step regarding staking pool deployment.